# Powershell script queues results of an if statement in a do while in a function

Tags: powershell

I'm using a function that I call from another script. It prompts a user for input until it gets back something that is not empty or null.

```
function GetUserInputValue($InputValue)
{
  do{
    $UserValue = Read-Host -Prompt $InputValue
    if (!$UserValue) { $InputValue + ' cannot be empty' }
  }while(!$UserValue)
  $UserValue
  return $UserValue
}
```

The issue is quite strange and likely a result of my lack of powershell experience. When I run the code and provide empty results, the messages from the if statement queue up and only display when I finally provide a valid input. See my console output below.

Console Results

```
test:

test:

test:

test:

test:

test:
test: 1

test cannot be empty

test cannot be empty

test cannot be empty

test cannot be empty

test cannot be empty

test cannot be empty

1
```

I can make this work however in the main file with hard coded values.

```
do{
    $Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Server'
    if (!$Server) { 'Server cannot be empty' }
}while(!$Server)
```

I'm working Visual Studio Code. This is a function I have in another file I've named functions.ps1.

I call this from my main file like this,

```
$test = GetUserInputValue("test")
$test
```

Comment: If you change it to `Write-Host 'Server cannot be empty'` does the delay go away?

Comment: Still there unfortunately. Good thought.

Comment: Are you in console host or ISE? Are you calling this inside a function or outer loop? I can't reproduce with the code you've posted.

Comment: I'll edit my post to include that info.

Comment: Ah I see now, however once I added `Write-Host` the issue went away and everything worked as expected (except that you are erroneously returning the value twice; I'll write this up in an answer).

Comment: If you made the change but don't see it working, make sure you re-run the code that _defines_ the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a naked value in a script like `"here's a message"` or `5` or even a variable by itself `$PID` what you're implicitly doing is calling `Write-Output` against that value.

That returns the object to the pipeline, and it gets added to the objects that that returns. So in a function, it's the return value of the function, in a `ForEach-Object` block it's the return value of the block, etc. This bubbles all the back up the stack / pipeline.

When it has nowhere higher to go, the host handles it.

The console host (`powershell.exe`) or ISE host (`powershell_ise.exe`) handle this by displaying the object on the console; this just happens to be the way they handle it. Another host (a custom C# application for example can host the powershell runtime) might handle it differently.

So what's happening here is that you are returning the message that you want to display, as part of the return value of your function, which is not what you want.

Instead, you should use `Write-Host`, as this writes *directly* to the host, skipping the pipeline. This is the correct command to use when you want to display a message to the user that must be shown (for other information you can use different commands like `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Warning`, `Write-Error`, etc.).

Doing this will give you the correct result, and prevent your informational message from being part of the return value of your function.

Speaking of which, you are returning the value twice. You don't need to do:

```
$UserValue
return $UserValue
```

The first one returns the value anyway (see the top of this answer); the second one does the same thing except that it returns immediately. Since it's at the end of the function anyway, you can use wither one, but only use one.

One more note: do not call PowerShell functions with parentheses:

```
$test = GetUserInputValue("test")
```

This works only because the function has a single parameter. If it had multiple params and you attempted to call it like a method (with parentheses and commas) it would not work correctly. You should separate arguments with spaces, and you should usually call parameters by name:

```
$test = GetUserInputValue "test"
# better:
$test = GetUserInputValue -InputValue "test"
```

Comment: You got it. That solved the problem. I really appreciate the the explanation. Day 3 of Powershell begins!